# Getting two versions of CSS

Tags: server-load

I was using `WP Super Cache` plugin to apply `style.css` file changes that I am doing all the time. But I found the following code which working much better:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); echo '?' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

The problem now that server having two CSS files named like that: `style.css?1402153121` which belong to code I have added, and another file named `style.css?ver=3.9.1` which has very old changes. I don't know if it a plugin issue or what! I have already deactivated the `WP Super Cache` plugin, but the file still existed. I am also using `cloudflare` plugin, I deactivated but nothing happened.

So how to get rid of that file `style.css?ver=3.9.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search your theme files for calls to `wp_enqueue_style()`, I bet that is what's adding an extra link to `style.css`.